# C# garbage collection with object references

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, object-reference

In C#, when I have two object **obj1**, **obj2** composed of a `List<string>` and I assign both of those objects to the same `List<string>` object.

If my reference to obj1 goes out of scope but my reference to obj2 does not, is obj1 still eligible for garbage collection, or are there some dependency issues because there is still a reference to the `List<string>` object?

Comment: +! Good question, but would you please write it out in code?

Comment: Seems like a good question, but I'm not really sure because it's not clear what's going on with *obj1*, *obj2*, and the List<string> objects... can you clarify?

Comment: The accepted answer here seems all wrong. Even though this was forever ago. Sounds to me like the OP described something like this: `var list = new List<string>(); object obj2 = list; { object obj1 = list; }`. Garbage collection doesn't affect variables. It affects objects. `obj1` and `obj2` do not get garbage collected. They exist on the stack and get cleaned up when the function or method returns. The instance first assigned to `list` is the only real object here and that can't be garbage collected until all references to it are destroyed (by going out of scope, or by garbage collection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `obj1` ***must be eligible*** for garbage collection.

You need to look at [`Jon Skeet's`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479262/how-garbage-collection-works-on-object-references/3479280#3479280) here. It clearly explains how garbage collection works on object references.

A nice tutorial for you on [`Object's Lifetime in C#`](http://mr-ponna.com/Article/21/Understanding-Object-Lifetime/).

Comment: Jon Skeet said, in his answer, "An object won't be garbage collected until it's no longer referenced by anything." In this case `obj1` and `obj2` reference the same object. So it is not eligible for collection.

Answer (score 1):

obj1 should be eligible for garbage collection as long as there are no references to obj1 itself.

Comment: This is true if you mean the pointer defined by `obj1` and not the instance of `List<string>` pointed to by `obj1`.

Answer (score 1):

> If my reference to obj1 goes out of
>   scope, but my reference to obj2 does
>   not, is obj1 still eligible for
>   garbage collection, or is there some
>   dependency issues because there is
>   still a reference to the List
>   object?

If I understand you correctly you mean both `obj1` and `obj2` are of type `List<string>` and both point to the **same** `List<string>` instance.

When `obj1` goes out of scope, there still will be still `obj2` as an active reference to the `List<string>` instance, so the list cannot be garbage collected.

If obj1 was part of a reference type on the heap (i.e. one of its properties) the memory space it occupied may be garbage collected as part of the outer object. If it was just a reference on the stack, GC will not be involved since the stack will be just unwound at the end of the method call when obj1 falls out  of scope.

Keep in mind that obj1 is just a reference (in a way a pointer) to an object on the heap - this object may be garbage collected only when no reference is pointing to it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are three uses of memory defined in this question:

- a reference to the single `List<string>` instance called `obj1`.
- a reference to the single `List<string>` instance called `obj2`.
- The single instance of `List<string>`.

if `obj1` goes out of scope, but `obj2` does not, then only the following remain after garbage collection:

- a reference to the `List<string>` instance called `obj2`.
- The instance of `List<string>`.

It is important to remember that C# abstracts away the concept of references in most cases so that you can safely think of `obj1` and `obj2` as being `List<string>` and not references, but reference they are.

It is likely that the `obj1` reference is in the local call stack as opposed to the instance itself which is likely on the heap. Therefore `obj1` (the reference) is only cleaned up when the call stack is unwound.

Answer (score -1):

If `obj1` is a member of a List, it's not available for garbage collection until the parent List is garbage collected.

So:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();

string a = "one";
l.Add(a);

{
    string b = "two";
    l.Add(b);
}
```

At the end of this listing, `a` is in scope, `b` is out of scope, but both still have references in the list `l`, so neither are eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - a comment on why it's wrong or a bad answer would be nice.

Comment: Probably because it answers the wrong question.